# Two conditions in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have three inputs for entering the time in HH:MM:SS format where I have three textfields for each respectively in a `jsp` page. I want my minute(MM) to be either 00 or 30 (for e.g: 12:00:00 or 12:30:00).

Here is my condition for this validation which I have done in `javascript`:

```
 if(time_mm!=00 || time_mm!=30)
 {
      alert("Enter a valid \"Time: Minutes(MM)\"");
      document.getElementById("time_mm").focus();
      document.getElementById("time_mm").value = "";
      return false;
 }
```

Here, if the input is `00`, the first condition `time_mm!=00` will be **false**, so it does no go inside the following processes and comes out of the statement which is fine. The problem arises when the input is `30`, where the first condition `time_mm!=00` will be **true** which goes into the following processes leaving the other condition `time_mm!=30` untouched.

So my problem is I am getting the alert "Enter the valid "Time: Minutes" even if my input is `30`.

Is my condition wrong??
Any Suggestions???

Comment: `time_mm != 00 && time_mm != 30`

Comment: well the minutes are not equal to `0` so theres your mistake. you want an `&&`

Comment: You are saying if time is not equal to 00 or not equal to 30. So 30 is not 00 so it will be true.

Comment: Logical operations work like this: `true || false = true`, `true && false = false` and `true && true = true`

Comment: @px06 is it possible it check `false || true`?

Comment: `if(!(time_mm==00 || time_mm==30))` -- need to change the "!" operator position only

Comment: @Joshua The only time the `||` operator return false is when you have `false || false`, and the only time the `&&` operator returns true is `true && true`, so `false || true` will be `true` because it contains _at least_ one `true` parameter.

Comment: @px yes it works as you say, but my doubt is, if the first condition is `true`, will it check the second condition??

Comment: @Joshua If you're using `&&` it will check both of the conditions given that the first one is `true`, in `||` there is no need to check the second condition if the first returns `true`, hence why you had the initial problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use triple equals to check the type also `===` and `'00' , '30'` as strings :

```
if(time_mm === "00" || time_mm === "30")
{
    alert("Valid Time Minutes");    
}else{
    alert("Enter a valid \"Time: Minutes(MM)\"");

    document.getElementById("time_mm").focus();
    document.getElementById("time_mm").value = "";

    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#validate', function(){
  var time_mm = document.getElementById("time_mm").value.split(':')[1];

  if(time_mm ==="00" || time_mm === "30")
  {
    console.log("Valid Time Minutes");    
  }else{
    console.log("Enter a valid \"Time: Minutes(MM)\"");
    document.getElementById("time_mm").focus();
    document.getElementById("time_mm").value = "";
    return false;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="time_mm" placeholder="HH:MM:SS"/>

<button id='validate'>validate</button>
```

Comment: `!=` will cast the numbers to strings in OP code so that's not the problem. And in your code, use strict operators.

Comment: Thansk @Tushar for your intervention, I prefer using string, else the `!= 00` has no sense, better to be `!=0`.

Comment: If I use && operator won't the conditions value become `false`?? Because if the input is 00 the first condition will be `true` and the second condition will be `false` which leads to `true && false==false`. If the input is 30 the first condition will be `false` and the second condition will be `true` which leads to `false && true==false.

Answer (score 3):

`if(time_mm!=00 || time_mm!=30)` will always be true because even if the value is 00, it won't be  equal to 30. You probably need && in this case.

change

```
if(time_mm!=00 || time_mm!=30)
```

to

```
if(time_mm!=00 && time_mm!=30)
```

Comment: i´d also note that, if `00` works theres another flaw in the code somewhere previously

Comment: Now only I noticed. Even the 00 is not working now :(

Comment: and probably you mean if varible==00 or variable == 30 then do the logic part.. @Joshua

Comment: the && operator works. :) Can you explain me the logic behind &&, because I thought the && operator's logic is if both the conditions are true the outcome is true. But here only one condition becomes true. Then how come it working??

Comment: can you post the final code? && works when all the conditions are true.

Comment: ` if(time_mm!=00 && time_mm!=30)
      {
       alert("Enter a valid \"Time: Minutes(MM)\"");
       document.getElementById("time_mm").focus();
       document.getElementById("time_mm").value = "";
    return false;
      } `

Comment: if time_mm is 00 or 33, it won't get executed else it will work in all..

Answer (score 1):

`if (time_mm != 00 || time_mm != 30)` is *always* true. How can it not be?

Consider writing

```
if (!(time_mm % 30)){ /*time_mm is not divisible by 30*/
```

instead where `%` denotes the *modulus*. This is arguably clearer, and means you don't get your `||` and `&&` mixed up.

Comment: can you explain the logic behind your suggestion? I am not able to get you

Comment: I've added a comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just need to change the negation operator as below

```
if(!(time_mm==00 || time_mm==30))
```

so if the values are not 00 or 30 then it will go in the IF loop.

Answer (score 0):

With an OR, it is *always* true. 'Time' cannot be equals to 0 *and* equals to 30, so it will always be not equal to 0 OR not equal to 30.

With the condition being always true, it will not work as you want it. You need to use AND instead of OR (`&&` instead of `||`)